# How can I extract this obvious event from this image?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, statistics, signal-processing

EDIT: I have found a solution :D thanks for the help.

I've created an image processing algorithm which extracts this image from the data. It's complex, so I won't go into detail, but this image is essentially a giant numpy array (it's visualizing angular dependence of pixel intensity of an object).

I want to write a program which automatically determines when the curves switch direction. I have the data and I also have this image, but it turns out doing something meaningful with either has been tricky. Thresholding fails because there are bands of different background color. Sobel operators and Hough Transforms also do not work well for this same reason.

This is really easy for humans to see when this switch happens, but not so easy to tell a computer. Any tips? Thanks!

[image: Tricky!]

Edit: Thanks all, I'm now fitting lines to this image after convolution with general gaussian and skeletonization of the result. Any pointers on doing this would be appreciated :)

[image: Skeletonized!]

Comment: You could use an [edge detection algorithm](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/linedet.htm), which consists of convolution of the image with a kernel. This would be similar to localized thresholding, avoiding the problem of different backgrounds. When you have the edges you could group the points to the corresponding lines, and with a spline interpolation scheme find the derivatives of the lines. Which would give you the turning points, and hence when the curve switches direction.

Comment: Most edge detection algorithms rely on a kind of thresholding that makes this image useless. And the problem is I am detecting curves, not just lines. what do you think?

Comment: The problem you have as I understand is that due to the different background intensities around the curves, a global threshold would not be appropriate. However, when performing localized thresholding only the nearest neighborhood of a point is compared, and thus avoids the aforementioned problem. 

From the edge detection scheme, you would get a matrix of the same size of the original image consisting of boolean values at indexes where edges are detected. From these points, you can retrieve your lines/curves.

Comment: Are the lines always roughly vertical?

Comment: Could you upload the image array somewhere?

Comment: sure, http://pastebin.com/iyqtgFAa. Thanks!

Comment: Now just need to figure out how to fit lines to the skeleton image.

Comment: Could you post your code for convolution with the general Gaussian and maybe edit your figure with the lines to the expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of Mark McCurry, I was able to get a good result.

[image: Original]

Step 1: Load original image. Remove background by subtracting median of each vertical column from itself.

```
no_background=[]
for i in range(num_frames):
    no_background.append(orig[:,i]-np.median(orig,1))
no_background=np.array(no_background).T
```

[image: Subtracted median.]

Step 2: Change negative values to 0.

```
clipped_background = no_background.clip(min=0)
```

[image: Clipped negative values.]

Step 3: Extract a 1D signal. Take weighted sum of the vertical columns, which relates the max intensity in a column to its position.

```
def exp_func(x):
    return np.dot(np.arange(len(x)), np.power(x, 10))/(np.sum(np.power(x, 10)))

weighted_sum = np.apply_along_axis(exp_func,0, clipped_background)
```

[image: Signal]

Step 4: Take the derivative of 1D signal.

```
conv = np.convolve([-1.,1],weighted_sum, mode='same')
pl.plot(conv)
```

[image: 1D Derivative]

Step 5: Determine when the derivative changes sign.

```
signs=np.sign(conv)
pl.plot(signs)
pl.ylim(-1.2,1.2)
```

[image: Convolution]

Step 6: Apply median filter to above signal.

```
filtered_signs=median_filter(signs, 5) #pick window size based on result. second arg and odd number.
pl.plot(filtered_signs)
pl.ylim(-1.2,1.2)
```

[image: Median Filter]

Step 7: Find the indices (frame locations) of when the sign switches. Plot result.

```
def sign_switch(oneDarray):
    inds=[]
    for ind in range(len(oneDarray)-1):
        if (oneDarray[ind]<0 and oneDarray[ind+1]>0) or (oneDarray[ind]>0 and oneDarray[ind+1]<0):
            inds.append(ind)
    return np.array(inds)

switched_frames = sign_switch(filtered_signs)
```

[image: Final Result]

Comment: This is a great answer to your own question! Thanks for sharing this with the rest of us. It seems robust enough as long as your median filter signal does not vary too much outside of the window you give it.

Comment: Thank you, I hope it's useful to someone.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a weighted dot product of successive columns to get a one-dimensional signal that is much easier to work with. You might be able to extract the patterns using this signal:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
A = np.loadtxt("img.txt")
N = A.shape[0]
L = np.logspace(1,2,N)
X = []
for c0,c1 in zip(A.T, A.T[1:]):
    x = c0.dot(c1*L) / (np.linalg.norm(c0)*np.linalg.norm(c1))
    X.append(x)

X = np.array(X)

import pylab as plt

plt.matshow(A,alpha=.5)
plt.plot(X*3-X.mean(),'k',lw=2)
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

*This is absolutely not a complete answer to the question, but a useful observation that is too long for a comment. I'll delete if a better answer comes along.*

Comment: Hi, I've thought about this for a while. Could you explain to me how the dot products are weighted? I'm glad I finally have a 1D signal, but I'm not seeing an patterns on any of the datasets on switches. Sure, the gap is the greatest at switch, but that is random as the vertical lines can become concave.

Comment: @awalllllll "...but that is random as the vertical lines can become concave.", I agree and this is why it isn't a valid answer yet (maybe just a clue for it). The idea behind this is that the columns contain spatial information (the center of the signal) as we move across. A weighted dot product gives some of that directional information, essentially not treating all points the same. I chose a log weight as I found it to be a smoother curve, though `linspace` worked too.

Answer (score 0):

For detecting tip positions or turning points, you might try using a corner detector on the original image (not the skeletonized one). As a corner detector the structure tensor could be applicable. The structure tensor is also useful for calculating the local orientation in an image.